# yahoomail is not working with TP-Link Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

when i connect my TP-Link Router with my modem that time yahoo mail is not working. without router means direct connect modem to computer that time yahoo mail is working.

Comment: Please explain "not working". Is the page not loading? Are there any errors? Do other websites work? etc.

Comment: when i open yahoomail that time "This webpage is not available" this error is occurred. and yes another all website are opening.

Comment: www.yahoo.com is also not opening..

Comment: Please, enter "ping www.yahoo.com" in a console window and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of firewall settings of.your router. Just for test purpose try switching off the. Firewall in your router or you can specificaly move the IP of your device (PC/laptop/mobile) outside of the firewall.